# Async/Await not unwrapping task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Could somebody please explain why I get the following error. The code below is for demonstration purposes only.

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Trim'

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(async x => await DoStuff());

var trimmedThings = items.Select(x => x.Trim());

public async Task<string> DoStuff() { //Do Stuff };
```

I thought using await would unwrap the task, exposing the string, so the type of items would be a `Enumerable<string>` rather than `Enumerable<Task<string>>`

Answer (score 2):

> I thought using await would unwrap the task

It does.  `await DoStuff()` returns a `string`, not a `Task<string>`, but as the method is an `async` method, the method needs to return a `Task`, so it will wrap up the return value into a task, meaning the end result of `async x => await DoStuff()` is identical to just writing `x => Dostuff()`  You're just  un-wrapping and then re-wrapping your <s>gift</s> `Task`.